# putExtra overwriting values for extractResult

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am experiencing a problem with using `intent.putExtra` to supply a `ResultReceiver` from one service to another service. Without using `putExtra` my intent handler gives me periodic results, but when it is included it cannot find anything but the value it added.

Without the `putExtra` the `mExtras->mMap->table` has as [0] `com.google.android.location.internal.EXTRA_RELEASE_VERSION` and as [2] `com.google.android.location.internal.EXTRA_ACTIVITY_RESULT` out of 3 entries.
When I include the `putExtra` in my code, the only entry in my `mExtras->mMap->table` is [2]  the `RESULT_RECEIVER`.

**IntentService handler**

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {         
  if (ActivityRecognitionResult.hasResult(intent)) {
    ActivityRecognitionResult result = ActivityRecognitionResult.extractResult(intent);
    DetectedActivity activity = result.getMostProbableActivity();
    ResultReceiver receiver = intent.getParcelableExtra(ActivityRecognitionService.RESULT_RECEIVER);             
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable("activity", activity);
    receiver.send(CODE, bundle);*/
  }  
}
```

`ActivityRecognitionService.ACTIVITY = activity;` is how I am currently getting the data across. It is one of the possibilities for data transfer mentioned on the Android developer pages, but I feel it's neater to do it using a `ResultReceiver` or other callback system.

**Class owning the intent, ActivityRecognitionService**

(which also happens to be a Service bound to an activity, for reference)

Note that creation and connection of `activityClient` is done in `onCreate()`

```java
static final String RESULT_RECEIVER = "com.example.myApp.RESULT_RECEIVER";  

void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityRecognitionService.this, ActivityRecognitionIntentService.class);
  intent.putExtra(ActivityRecognitionService.RESULT_RECEIVER, resultReceiver);
  PendingIntent callbackIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
  activityClient.requestActivityUpdates(DETECTION_INTERVAL, callbackIntent);
}
```

I don't get any errors, it simply fails to find any result in `hasResult(intent)` when `putExtra` is included.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this also. I believe its because the pendingIntent passed into requestActivityUpdates() has the FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT set (which from my understanding overwrites the extras in the intent - giving you back what you pass in it this case).

I got around this by passing the DetectedActivity (as it implements parcelable) back to my calling service in a startService Intent and process it in onStartCommand.

ActivityRecognition IntentService:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (ActivityRecognitionResult.hasResult(intent)) {

         ActivityRecognitionResult result = ActivityRecognitionResult.extractResult(intent);

         DetectedActivity detected = result.getMostProbableActivity();

         Intent intent= new Intent(this, CallingService.class);
         intent.putExtra(CallingService.EXTRA_ACTIVITY, detected);

         startService(intent);
     }
}
```

Calling Service:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {  

    if(intent.hasExtra(CallingService.EXTRA_ACTIVITY)){

        DetectedActivity result = intent.getParcelableExtra(CallingService.EXTRA_ACTIVITY);
            // REST OF PROCESSING
    }

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Hope this helps or someone else can chip in with an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck on this as well, but finally found a suitable solution.

In the end, I created a new BroadcastIntent from within the ActivityRecognitionService, and registered a BroadcastReceiver in my manifest.

```
    if (ActivityRecognitionResult.hasResult(intent)) 
    {
        ActivityRecognitionResult result = ActivityRecognitionResult.extractResult(intent);
        String myActivity = getFriendlyName(result.getMostProbableActivity().getType());

        if(Globals.SHOW_LOG)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "ActivityRecognitionResult: " + myActivity);
            Log.d(TAG, result.toString());
        }
        // YOUR CODE GOES HERE!
        // Store the current activity in SharedPreferences or whatever

        // Broadcast the event to the receiver
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(this, ReceiverActivityRecognition.class);
        broadcastIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        broadcastIntent.putExtra(Globals.ARG_RECEIVER_EXTRA, myActivity);
        sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    }
```

In the manifest you need to register the BroadcastReceiver:

```
    <receiver android:name=".ReceiverActivityRecognition"/>
```

Hope this helps someone!